# Manipulate and global assignments

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I've a (perhaps too) basic questions that has been bugging me for a while. Manipulate seems to ignore global assignments. For instance the following does not result in the obvious output one would expect:

```
a = x*b;
Manipulate[Plot[a, {x, 0, 1}], {b, 1, 2}].
```

Instead, to had a 45 degree line, one had to redefine the a object within manipulation:

```
Manipulate[x*b;Plot[a, {x, 0, 1}], {b, 1, 2}].
```

Is there a way to have `Manipulate` to use the global assignment `a=x*b`?
Thanks!!

Comment: No always but often you can find interesting facts in **Details & Options** part for given function. For `Manipulate` below the table with options there is a bullet: `Manipulate generates a DynamicModule object, with the variables u, v, etc. specified as local. `

Comment: Try making a snapshot of your `Manipulate` and you will see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you introduced `{b, 1, 2}` as a control, you made `b` a local variable that shadows your global `b`. Two possible fixes are:

```
Manipulate[a := x b; Plot[a, {x, 0, 1}], {b, 1, 2}]
```

or

```
Manipulate[Plot[a[x, b], {x, 0, 1}],
  {b, 1, 2},
  Initialization :> (a[x_, b_] := x b)]
```